# How to mock EventHubProducerClient from Azure Event Hubs?

Tags: unit-testing, azure-eventhub, fakeiteasy

I need to write unit tests for the EventHubProducerClient class, which many instances of used in my repo. Modifying the original class is not an option. More specifically, I need to mock the CreateBatchAsync() method of the EventHubProducerClient class, as well as the SendAsync() method. Does anyone know how this can be accomplished? I am noob when it comes to mocking. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

I tried creating a interface wrapper to implement the mock methods instead, but not only does this modify the original constructor, I also just couldn't get it to work. If you have any advice or solutions that would be very helpful (with code examples).

Answer (score 1):

To mock the `CreateBatchAsync`, you'll need to use the [EventHubsModelFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventhubsmodelfactory?view=azure-dotnet), which allows you to inject behavior to control what events the batch accepts and have access to the events that were added.

At a high level, this looks something like:

```cs
List<EventData> eventsInTheBatch = new();

EventDataBatch dataBatchMock = EventHubsModelFactory.EventDataBatch(
    batchSizeBytes : 500,
    batchEventStore : eventsInTheBatch,
    batchOptions : new CreateBatchOptions(),  
    eventData => eventsInTheBatch.Count < 5);
```

A full end-to-end example of mocking the `EventHubProducerClient` with batches can be found in the [Mocking Client Types](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample11_MockingClientTypes.md#publishing-events-with-the-eventhubproducerclient) sample.

For more general information, the approach used to support unit testing in the Azure SDK libraries is described in the [Azure SDK Design Guidelines](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/dotnet_introduction.html#dotnet-mocking) and discussed further in [Unit testing and mocking with Azure SDK .NET](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/unit-testing-and-mocking/).